# Translate SQL referencing parent clause to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm basically trying to get this SQL query working in SQLAlchemy:

```
SELECT p.id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM response r WHERE <conditions on r> AND r.prompt_id = p.id)
  FROM prompt p WHERE p.<conditions>;
```

I have it all working except for the reference to p.id in the subquery:

```
# used all over application
def filter_prompt(search_string, customer_id, state):
  prompts = Prompt.query
  if search_string:
    prompts = prompts.filter(Prompt.id.ilike('%' + search_string + '%'))
  elif customer_id, state, etc
    ... more filtering ...
  return prompts
```

I have a special case where I need to return the number of related objects, so I'm attempting to just add a subquery column:

```
prompts = filter_prompt(...)
count_subquery = session.query(func.count('response')).filter(Response.validated_at>=date, Response.prompt_id == Prompt.id).subquery()
prompts_with_response_count = prompts.add_column(count_subquery)
```

The problem is that `Prompt.id` is not properly resolved to the id for that row. How would I properly translate the above SQL to SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a subquery in a select statement, you don't do `subquery but instead do`as_scalar` (which tells SQLAlchemy that there will be a scalar result, one row, one column):

```
count_subquery = session.query(func.count('response')).filter(Response.validated_at>=date, Response.prompt_id == Prompt.id).as_scalar()
```